# How do I fail all scenarios without starting the test?

Tags: java, getgauge

i have a question I would be glad if you answer. how do I make all specifications is fail with getgauge(java) according to any situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeforeSpec` hook to fail all the spec. You can throw an exception or add an assert failure in the `BeforeSpec` hook which will cause the specifications to fail.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I want the driver to never stand up.